# How does force amplifier works?

Tags: ingress

What does Force Amplifier mod do to a portal?

I haven't found any info about it.. So maybe some people have tried and can share experiences?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Force amp increases the force of portal attack (when you're attacking a portal)
rare:
1st = +2x
2nd = +0.5x > 2.5x
3rd = +0.25x > 2.75x ~ 2.8x
4th = +0.125x > 2.875x ~ 3.0x
example :
L6 portal without FA : base damage = 400 XM
with FA : base damage*2 = 800 XM

I don't know the numbers for very rare or common

Comment: By saying 'portal attack' do you mean XM lost when attacking portal (minus weapon usage cost)?

Comment: Yes, I tried to clear that up in my answer now.

Comment: FAs have nothing to do with your own portals ability to take attacks faster. They increase the durability of shields/turrets.

Comment: Does it influence the portal attack when hacking?

Comment: There aren't "Common" and "Very Rare" kinds of "Force Amp" and "Turret" mods. (not yet at least)

Answer (score -6):

It doubles the range of a portal.

Not sure if you can use more than one amplifier-mod at one portal though.

Comment: He didn't ask about link amplifiers, but about FORCE amplifiers.